# How to check the Number of factors of n is odd or even?

Tags: refactoring

How to check the "Number of factors" of "n" is odd or even?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Only the perfect square numbers (i.e. 4,16,25....) have odd number of factors.
Others have even.